# How do I design a system to find top K trending posts in a time window

Tags: algorithm, system-design

I am working on a system design problem and I need to surface the top K trending posts in 5 min, 1 hour and 24 hour windows.

I understand the approach of finding Top K element by using a hash map to keep track of frequency and a heap to sort K items by frequency.

But, I am not sure how to account for time components. I keep reading about buckets/counters etc but I am unable to come up with a solution.

I am looking to understand the algorithm first before working out how this would be built in a distributed fashion.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You will most likely need to do caching and analysis on your data. Something like Cassandra is well suited to a problem like this, in my opinion, as it can index on a timestamp field, which is a native data type in Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self-balancing binary search tree instead of a heap: These have the same time and space complexities for all operations permitted by heaps, but also allow deletion of an element in O(log n) time (rather than O(n) time). Most languages implement some kind of "ordered dictionary" container abstraction using these trees; in C++, it's called `map<T, U>`.

For each time window, maintain a separate tree. Let's consider the 5m window for concreteness.

Whenever a new element arrives, add it to the tree, and schedule a 5-minute timer to remove it again; the insertion and the removal cost O(log n) each, where n is the maximum size the tree grows to -- that is, the maximum number of events that occur in a 5-minute window. To find the top k items, simply begin an inorder traversal of the tree, and halt after reporting k items. This takes O(k) time, and allows different choices of k. Make sure that either you, or your language's underlying container implementation, allows concurrent modification of the container.

This approach is simple, but scheduling a timer per new element may incur a lot of overhead. You can alternatively perform deletions "lazily": When a new element xNew arrives at time tNew, add xNew to the tree as usual, but instead of scheduling a timer, also:

1. Add (xNew, tNew) to a separate FIFO queue.
2. Extract elements (x, t) from the queue until t >= tNew - 5.